# Deserialize object with Jackson

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, jackson, fasterxml

I would like to know if there is an option in FasterXML Jackson (or any other pure way) to deserialize JSON in such way, that when I have JSON response from API like this:

```
{"id": "1234", "name": "name1"}
```

then automatically it will be mapped on the fly to class hierarchy like this:

```
class Person (
   val sellerId: SellerId,
   val name: String
)

class SellerId (
   val id: String
)
```

I am interesting mainly in fact how to make on the fly deserialization from top level "id": String to nested "sellerid" which is object containing this id.

Comment: I've had similar task and ended up implementing custom deserialiser which was registered in the jackson module using `addDeserializer`. I'd suggest to make `SellerId` implement some sort of interface `IValueBox<T: Any> { val id: T }` and register your custom deserializer for IValueBox. Then, you can create an instance of the `SellerId` and similar value classes via reflection.

Comment: Did below answer helped you to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. define a `String`-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from `String` value for `SellerId` class.
2. Annotate `sellerId` property with `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAlias` or `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty` annotations. Something like: `@JsonProperty("id") val sellerId: SellerId`